# How do I add headers to a response from spark, when using a transformer

Tags: java, java-8, spark-java

I have this:

```
get ("/test", (req, resp) -> {
    return repository.getAll();
}, new JsonTransformer());
```

My transformer looks like:

```
public class JsonTransformer implements ResponseTransformer {

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

    public JsonTransformer() {
    }

    @Override
    public String render(Object o) throws Exception {
        return om.writeValueAsString(o);
    }
}
```

I've tried adding a header using the header funtion on response like so:

```
get ("/test", (req, resp) -> {
    resp.header("Content-Type", "application/json");
    return repository.getAll();
}, new JsonTransformer());
```

And I've tried this which I found in the docs:
I think this sets the accept-type

```
get ("/test", "application/json", (req, resp) -> {
    return repository.getAll();
}, new JsonTransformer());
```

But nowhere I'm getting `application/json` as my `Content-Type` header

Comment: i would consider changing your spark tag. That seems to be for the apache spark computation framework, not the ws framework.

Comment: How did you solve it? I added "response.type("application/json");" It works but is there any nicer way?

Comment: @Gabriel no thats it. Thats what I did too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You set the `Content-Type` of the response using the `response.type` function like so:

```
get("test", (req, resp) -> {
    resp.type("application/json");
    return repository.getAll() 
}, new JsonTransformer());
```

Answer (score 17):

Well after researching I found an elegant way to resolve this, I created an before method.

```
before((request, response) -> response.type("application/json"));
```

This would add the response type to json.

You can add it in after route but it may become troublesome later on. thx albertjan for your tip :)

Comment: If json is your primary response-type the before route is a good solution. The after route could become troublesome later on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did try both but i ended up using before as it was cleaner and i still have the opportunity to change the response.type in the route itself if needed.

Answer (score 2):

The third option is to use an after filter:

```
after((request, response) -> response.type("application/json"));
```

Please see: http://sparkjava.com/documentation#filters